# How to close a TinyBox with Javascript?

Tags: tinymce

I have a login in TinyBox. When click login it redirect to file which echo with PHP login successful or wrong password or user, how to close that tinybox with JavaScript or something other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me:

```
window.parent.TINY.box.hide()
```